# Fetch data from table and display it in bootstrap table

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fetch data from table insdie php script and displaying in table. This php script is called by button click event.

Here is the php code which does this:

```
        while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        
            echo '<div class = "c2">        
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr class="active">
                                      <td class="active"></td>
                                      <td class="active">'.$row['date'].'</td>
                                      <td class="success">'.$row['time'].'</td>
                                      <td class="warning">'.$row['username'].'</td>
                                      <td class="danger">'.$row['user_follower_count'].'</td>
                                      <td class="info">'.$constant.'</td>
                                      <td class="active">'.$row['tweet_text'].'</td>
                                      <td class="success">...dfd</td>
                                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            ';

        }
```

However the content display looks messed.

I have used bootstrap css here

Like

[image]

How can I display so that all rows appears with same width in proper manner?

Content is displayed when button is clicked.

Comment: If you want to display all data in _one_ table, then don’t create a _new_ table for every single record …

Comment: thanks, i didnt notice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    echo '<div class="c2"><table class="table table-condensed"><tbody>';
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            echo '<tr class="active">
                                      <td class="active"></td>
                                      <td class="active">'.$row['date'].'</td>
                                      <td class="success">'.$row['time'].'</td>
                                      <td class="warning">'.$row['username'].'</td>
                                      <td class="danger">'.$row['user_follower_count'].'</td>
                                      <td class="info">'.$constant.'</td>
                                      <td class="active">'.$row['tweet_text'].'</td>
                                      <td class="success">...dfd</td>
                                </tr>';

} 
echo '</tbody></table></div>';
```